# Can't change text in textview from broadcast receiver

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver

I have the following code of activity:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.mikhailovskii.androidacademytask8.R
import com.mikhailovskii.androidacademytask8.data.service.ProgressIntentService
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class ProgressActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val receiver = ActivityBroadcastReceiver(Handler())

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        tv_progress.text="0"

        val intentFilter = IntentFilter(ProgressIntentService.INTENT_ACTION)
        registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter)

        btn_intent_service.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, ProgressIntentService::class.java)
            startService(intent)
        }

        btn_service.setOnClickListener {
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        unregisterReceiver(receiver)
    }

    //FIXME handler1 seems strange, but passing to constructor doesn't work
    class ActivityBroadcastReceiver (handler1: Handler) : BroadcastReceiver() {

        private val handler = handler1

        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
            val progress = intent?.getIntExtra(ProgressIntentService.EXTRA_KEY_OUT, 0)
            handler.post { tv_progress.text  = progress }
        }

    }

}
```

I need to change the text in `tv_progress` from `BroadcastReceiver`. For this purpose I added Handler here. But name of tv is highlighted in red and studio writes that

> Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch

So, what's the reason of this problem and how can I solve it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nested classes in Kotlin are not inner classes, by default. You must explicitly declare them as `inner`.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the name on broadcast in below line :

val intentFilter = IntentFilter(ProgressIntentService.INTENT_ACTION)